# Macro to generate function implementation by its definition?

Tags: nim-lang

Would it be possible to automate writing the implementation for remote function?

If written by hand it would look like code below. Having both function declaration and implementation is important.

```
proc rcall*[A, B, R](fn: string, a: A, b: B, _: type[R]): R =
  echo (fn, a, b)

proc multiply(a, b: int): int

proc multiply(a, b: int): int =
  rcall("multiply", a, b, int)
```

I would like to automate it and write it as

```
proc rcall*[A, B, R](fn: string, a: A, b: B, _: type[R]): R =
  echo (fn, a, b)

proc multiply(a, b: int): int

remotefn multiply
```

And the `remotefn` macro should look at function definition and generate its implementation as `rcall("multiply", a, b, int)`, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be possible to automate writing the implementation ...

Yes, it would be possible to automate implementation of just about anything using nim macros that take `typed` argument (and then `getTypeImpl`)

```
import std/macros

macro dumpImpl(arg: typed): untyped =
  echo arg.getTypeImpl().treeRepr()
  
  
proc rcall*[A, B, R](fn: string, a: A, b: B, _: type[R]): R =
  echo (fn, a, b)

proc multiply(a, b: int): int

proc multiply(a, b: int): int =
  rcall("multiply", a, b, int)
  
  
dumpImpl multiply
```

Shows that `multiply` type (function signature) has the following structure:

```
ProcTy
  FormalParams
    Sym "int"
    IdentDefs
      Sym "a"
      Sym "int"
      Empty
    IdentDefs
      Sym "b"
      Sym "int"
      Empty
  Empty
```

Although it is important to keep in mind that overloaded procedures cannot be easily resolved based only on name (because, well, there are *many* implementations). The most obvious choice would be to still use `typed` argument, but pass some parameter to disambiguate the function call

```
import std/macros

macro dumpImpl(arg: typed): untyped =
  echo arg.treeRepr()
  
  
proc overload(a: string) = discard
proc overload(a: int) = discard


dumpImpl overload
# ClosedSymChoice - lists all possible overloads with their respective symbols
#   Sym "overload"
#   Sym "overload"

dumpImpl overload("123")
#Call
#  Sym "overload"
#  StrLit "123"

dumpImpl overload(123)
#Call
#  Sym "overload"
#  IntLit 123
```

As a small (personal) side note - when you are talking about nim macros the question should mostly be not "if this is even possible?" but rather "what is the most optimal way to do this?". It might require some knowledge of macro tricks, but it is possible to implement almost anything.

EDIT1 (add implementation code example, reply to question in comments):

```
import std/[macros]

proc rcall*[A, B, R](fn: string, a: A, b: B, _: type[R]): R =
  echo (fn, a, b)

macro remotefn(fn: typed) =
  let fname = fn.str_val()
  # `quote do` generates hygienic identifiers - i.e. all new
  # variables/functions introduced by it are unique and not visible in
  # global. To fix this you need to explicitly create identifier for your
  # procedure using `ident`

  let
    multId = ident("multiply") # < Function name identifier

    # Same goes for variables - nim does have a name-based overloading, so
    # you need to make sure function arguments use the same identifiers as
    # the original one
    aId = ident("a")
    bId = ident("b")

  result = quote do:
    proc `multId`(`aId`, `bId`: int): int =
      rcall(`fname`, 1, 1, int)

  echo result.toStrLit()

proc multiply(a, b: int): int
remotefn multiply
```

Comment: Thanks! As for overloaded functions, it would be ok to don't allow overloaded functions to be remote functions. Or maybe append arg types to its name in the string key.

Comment: But can the macro generate the implementation itself when only the definition of the function available? I generated the implementation, but it still complains that proc doesn't have the implementation https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2Wx8

Comment: @AlexCraft updated my answer with implementation example - too small to fit into the comment section.