# How to get function name as string in macro/template?

Tags: nim-lang

Can't figure out how to get function name as string in macro.

The code below should generate `rlisten("multiply", multiply)` but it won't compile, [playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2WwN).

```
import macros

proc rlisten*[A, B, R](fn: string, op: proc(a: A, b: B): R): void =
  echo fn

macro remotefn(fn): void =
  quote do:
    rlisten($`fn`, `fn`) # It should generte `rlisten("multiply", multiply)`

proc multiply(a, b: int): int = discard
remotefn multiply
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to accept `typed` or `untyped` parameters to a macro. In this particular case you need to use `typed` argument in order to be able to access the function **symbol** (symbols are identifiers replaced by type resolution pass of the compiler).

```
import macros

proc rlisten*[A, B, R](fn: string, op: proc(a: A, b: B): R): void =
  echo fn

macro remotefn(fn: typed): void =
  echo fn.treeRepr()
  # ^ Show tree representation of the argument. In this particular case it is just a
  # single function symbol.
  let name = fn.strVal()
  echo "Function name is ", name

proc multiply(a, b: int): int = discard
remotefn multiply
```

Outputs

```
Sym "multiply"
Function name is multiply
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is *the* most optimal way of passing function name. I partially based my response on your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150226/macro-to-generate-function-implementation-by-its-definition/67150407?noredirect=1#comment118694399_67150407 earlier question. If you just need a name you can just pass `untyped` identifier and retrieve string from it.

Comment: thanks, it works! :) https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2WwW